# How to enable blobstore and imageservice in android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, blobstore

I read through [**this link**](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/) and am a little bit confused on how I should integrate *blobstore api* in  my project.

I added appengine library under WEB-INF folder and I copied the code sample of upload and serve from the link I posted above. I added tomcat server and tested sample servlet programs it works fine.

But when I test the code it throws me

```
HTTP Status 500 - Must be called from a blob upload callback request.
```

---

```
type 
    Exception 

report
    message must be called from a blob upload callback request.

description 
    The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Must be called from a blob upload callback request.
com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceImpl.getUploads(BlobstoreServiceImpl.java:169)
com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.BlobstoreServiceImpl.getUploadedBlobs(BlobstoreServiceImpl.java:152)
my.Upload.doPost(Upload.java:34)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

I dont know how can I add the blobstore service.
What I am trying to get is  just to be able to upload an image and get back a blob type which I will convert to a bitmap and put on imageview. What's going wrong here and how can I fix this?